# Accidently changed android:Versioncode to a higher value, what now?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have been updating my **app version code as 1,2,3.....15** and last time i accidentally changed the version code to a higher number instead

```
android:versionCode="165"
```

will this cause any problems? i have read that version code is used to recognize the downgrade or upgrade of app,So on my next update shall i put

```
android:versionCode="166"
```

or

```
android:versionCode="16"
```

Is there any limit for this version code integer? If its just an integer, what will happen if i put it like 1000 or more?

Comment: So what's the error? Can't you change it?

Comment: @JoanColmenero I guess he published the app with VersionCode as 165

Comment: @joan yes i uploaded my app with version code 165 accidently, so i didn't knew if i should put 16 or 166 this time when i update the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [Versioning Your App (Google Dev)](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html):

> android:versionCode — An integer value that represents the version of the application code, relative to other versions.
>   The value is an integer so that other applications can programmatically evaluate it, for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set the value to **any integer you want**, however you should make sure that each successive release of your application uses a greater value. The system does not enforce this behavior, but increasing the value with successive releases is normative.

Therefore, the answer for your question is NO. No problem with your version code. And you must increase your version code in next update (as described above).

Comment: you mean i should put 166 on next update, what will happen if i put 16 instead? from user perspective what is the change? They will not get the update notification if i put 16 on the update?

Comment: You cannot update a app with a smaller version code to Google Play store.  Even if you can, Android will not allow the app to update to a version with smaller version code. User will need to uninstall the 166 version first before installing your version 16.

Comment: @MrFarts: 1. As you see the quote above, you must use greater value or else you cant upload your apk to publish in Google Play Store.
2. Applications and publishing services should not display this version value to users.

Answer (score 2):

It would be `android:versionCode="166"`

I think there is no limit like you said 1000 or more. Just make sure that next updated version is greater than previous one.

If you worry about the code as Integer then its limit will be 2,147,483,647. So, increment by one would take your life time.

Answer (score 1):

I see everywhere that the android versionCode max value is 2,147,483,647 so "increment by one would take your life time. " but...

I used to choose my versionCode value with this pattern : *YYYYmmddHHiiss*, followed by a 2 more digits value (eg. as recommended for DNS serial numbers).

If you're using Cordova or Phonegap, **don't do this.**

Their build script tries to add a "0" to your versionCode, and thus can make it too big for an int... for example, *today* could give *20,150,623,010*.

So the build script fails...

Comment: Btw, I'have opened an issue : https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer/issues/326